# composer global require laravel/installer stucked on "Changed current directory"

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am currently setting up my laravel on my new machine. but when i tried to run composer global require laravel/installer it seems like the command was stuck on Changed current directory to C:/Users/sheer/AppData/Roaming/Composer. I waited for almost an hour to finish the installation but i am still stuck on this changed current directory part.

[image]

Comment: What version of composer are you using?

Comment: my Composer version 1.9.1 2019-11-01 17:20:17 @Rwd

Comment: Please can you show the output of `composer global diagnose`.

Comment: @Rwd it says OK to all checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install composer from there https://getcomposer.org/download/ 
Then run this command to create the Laravel project:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.8.*"
```

Comment: running t his command works. not sure why `composer global require laravel/install` is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

when you try to use composer with gloab option , you mean that hey composer I want to save and have this type of dependency for future use ( something like laravel does ).
so it switches to it's installation folder and tries to install the dependency within it.
As you can see now the default directory for you is : `C:/path/to/composer` which is not writable without admin permission on windows.
so you eaither have to change the installation directory of composer, which is not suggested or you have to Right Click on `CMD` and click on Run `As Administrator`.

check and see how it works.this type of problems are most of the times permission problems.

Comment: running as admin dont work as well. i tried to untick the read-only of the composer folder properties. but still dont work as it should.

Comment: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.8.*"
` this command downloads the project every time and the one you mentioned tries to cache it with a command.so no problem working with this one.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, when I navigated to the **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer** and found out that the vendor folder is not there but since there is a **composer.json** that requires **laravel/installer**, I opened up a terminal and run **"composer install"**. After the installation, you will be able to run a command **"laravel new project-name"**.